# iOS: how to add length of a NSData as its two bytes header?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata, nsmutabledata

I have a NSData and I would like to append its length in its header as hex digits. I am able to do this using following code:

```
unsigned int len = [data length];

NSMutableData *sendData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:&len length:2];
[sendData appendData:data];
```

result from above code for len = 5 is "05 00" but I want "00 05" instead. Does anyone know how to do that?

Header is always going to be of length 2.

Thanks,

Comment: This likely has to do with the endianness, try `unsigned int len = CFSwapInt16BigToHost([data length]);`

Comment: There's an article referring to endian swapping at http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c-r2091

Comment: @Scott Shouldn't that be `CFSwapInt16HostToBig`? The goal is to go from the current 'host` endian to the desired big endian.

Comment: BTW - here's a good example of big versus little endian: http://www.chucklecloud.com/chuckles/1270

Comment: @rmaddy: You're right, I got confused there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below addumes (as you do) that the length is less than 65536 (two bytes). So you need to use:

```
uint16_t len = CFSwapInt16HostToBig([data length]);
NSMutableData *sendData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:&len length:2];
[sendData appendData:data];
```

The list of available function are described in de document below in the apple developer library:

[Byte-Order Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Your swap is backwards. You want to go from `host` to big endian. `Host` always represents what you have on the current device. You should also assign the raw length to a `uint16_t` variable first, then swap that variable.

Comment: My mistake. Most of the time I need to do the reverse, so I accepted the auto-completion in Xcode before reading the full text… Thanks for seeing it.